# Improving a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a simple sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM marketing
WHERE type = 'email'
  AND id NOT IN (
                SELECT id
                FROM marketing
                WHERE type = 'letter'
                )
ORDER BY id;
```

It takes a really long time to run, and I assume it has to do with the select in the where statement (There are a large number of ids), but I can't come up with a way to improve it.

First can this be the reason the query is so slow, and second any suggestion on how to improve it?

Edit:

Database System: MySql

Id is indexed but but is not a primary key in this table; it is a foreign key.

Comment: How big is your table and 'type' does it have index?

Comment: `WHERE type='email'` and `WHERE type='letter'` seems redundant.  You basically said type has to be "email" but then double check that it isnt "letter". Can't you just take out the nested SELECT?

Comment: The entire `not in` bit seems redundant. If you've found a record with `type = 'email'`, then how could it possibly be in a list of records with `type = 'letter'`?

Comment: @DavidStarkey I'm assuming that an id can have many types in the marketing table.  To be clearer: there is nothing here that tells us that Id is actually an identiy column or a unique index of the table.

Comment: does `NOT EXISTS` perform any differently?

Comment: is `id` a primary key?  Also, which SQL is this?  Sql Server?  Oracle?  Ingres?

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: Edited to say I'm using mysql and that the key is a foreign key which also explains why the not in isn't redundant since there are multiple entries for the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative to your query, although according to Quassnoi [here (MySQL)](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) it should perform similarly.

```
   select email.id
     from marketing email
left join marketing letter on letter.type='letter' and letter.id=email.id
    where email.type='email' and letter.id is null
 group by email.id
 order by email.id;
```

The three main ways of writing this type of query are NOT IN, NOT EXISTS (correlated) or LEFT JOIN/IS NULL. Quassnoi compares them for MySQL (link above), [SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/), [Oracle](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/), and [PostgreSQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a known pattern for queries of this type: get all rows which do not match another set.

```
select id from marketing m1
left outer join marketing m2 on m1.id = m2.id and m2.type = 'letter'
where m1.type = 'email' and m2.id IS NULL
```

This will get all the rows in marketing which are of type 'email' and there does not exist an id with type 'letter' to match. If you want the other set, use IS NOT NULL. A proper index on the id column is all you need for max execution speed, with type as a covered column.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct id
from   marketing a
where  type = 'email'
and    not exists (
           select 'X'
           from   marketing b
           where  a.id = b.id
           and    type = 'letter' )
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also phrase this query as an aggregation query.  The conditions you are looking for is that an `id` has at least one row where `type = 'email'` and no rows where `type = 'letter'`:

```
select id
from marketing m
group by id
having SUM(case when type = 'letter' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       SUM(case when type = 'email' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

It is possible that this query would run faster with an index on `marketing(id, type)`.  The `order by id` is redundant in MySQL because the `group by` does the ordering.